# What causes a big rip?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation, dark-energy

If dark energy has $w<-1$ you get the Big rip scenario, where dark energy becomes more and more powerful until it eventually rips all matter apart. Why does this occur? Why does having $w<-1$ result in a big rip?

Comment: Do you understand the [Friedmann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations)?